# NodeJS : prevent application to crash on error

Tags: node.js, error-handling

When an error occurs in NodeJS application, the server may crash and stop if an exception occurs.

How can I prevent this situation so that the server never stops on error, but returns and error code instead ?

--
EDIT

Here is a method which causes a server crash (table foo doesn't exist) :

```
app.get('/articles/list', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('select * from foo', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });
});
```

-- BEST SOLUTION
Finally, I found the best solution for me :
http://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/

In summary, it consists in using a cluster of server, and to restart a server when it exits

Comment: this seems a bit vague, you can always add a try catch  on a critical area

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `express`, you can use this

```
function clientErrorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
   if (req.xhr) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
    } else {
      next(err)
   }
}

app.use(clientErrorHandler);
```

I suggest you to ready this [article](http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practices-of-node-js-error-handling/), it will clarify a lot for you.
JFK, be aware of async error catching, most common error, once you have async stuff which is wrapped in `try-catch`.
Also, avoid usage of

```
process.on("uncaughException", () => {....})
```

This is quite bad, because when an uncaught exception is thrown you can’t reliably continue your program at this point.Let it fail and restart with `daemonizer's` like `pm2`, `forever` and etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use express indeed, but clientErrorHandler doesn't work for me (I've edited my question to insert a code sample)

Comment: @hadf I updated answer, answer was not full.
Anyway, your app is crushed because you just re-throw error which is not handled anywhere else.
          if (err) {
              res.status(500).send(new Error(err));
          }

Comment: Thank you, I've found the best solution for me. It consists in using cluster in order to relaunch node server when it crashes

Answer (score 1):

As general rule, you **should** handle all errors and promise rejects in your code to avoid uncaught Exceptions.

For **errors**: using [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement

For **promises**: using [.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method

Btw Node permits you to intercept an `uncaughtExceptions` or `unhandledRejection` events, but is not a good practice to handle errors at this level and prevent program exits, because can generate unpredictable behaviours.

Answer (score -2):

Use try catch... for parts of code, which throws exception

```
 try{
       //youre code here
    }catch(error){
       console.log(error)
    }
```